# displaying an image as big as possible

Tags: css

How can I scale up a image as much as possible without changing the picture ratio. So its either 100% width or 100% height

```html
<div class="container"><img src=""></div>
```

Comment: What does as much as possible means?

Comment: until its either 100% width or 100% height

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use CSS background which is recommended in this case. You can read more about CSS backgrounds [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background).

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/200) center/cover no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

2. You can use the image tag (as you did) and set the *width & height* property to *100%*.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
</div>
```

**P.S.: You can set the *height* to *auto* so the image becomes responsive.**

Answer (score 0):

With that, you can give whatever width or height value to the container, and the image will fit in with a correct look:

```css
.container{
  height : 500px;
  width : 500px;
}

.container img{
  width : 100%;
  height : 100%;
  object-fit : cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
img{   
 object-fit: contain;
}
```

use this for the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `object-fit: cover`, the image will be sized to maintain its aspect ratio while filling the element’s entire content box

```css
.img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
      <image
        src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/close-up-of-cat-wearing-sunglasses-while-sitting-royalty-free-image-1571755145.jpg"
        alt="test"
        class="img"
      />
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `object-fit: contain;` for the image

```css
.image-container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
}
.image-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container" style="height: 500px;">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<div class="image-container" style="width: 500px;">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_girl.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```